# Fetching Excel cells directly with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple Excel files in a folder and all of them have fixed templates. I want to fetch cells from them and then put in a new workbook.

I use 2 Excel files as an example in a folder to explain. I have a folder called `MyFolder` and two Excel files in it. (`file1.xlsx` and `file2.xlsx`)

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

What I want is like:

[image: pic3]

So, I tried:

```
Sub Merge_Files()
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim xFolder As Folder
Dim xFile As File
Dim Main_WB As Workbook, New_WB As Workbook
Dim X As Integer, Y As Integer
Set Main_WB = ActiveWorkbook
Set xFolder = FSO.GetFolder("C:\Desktop\MyFolder\") 

    Cells(1, "A").Value = "Company"
    Cells(1, "B").Value = "CB"
    Cells(1, "C").Value = "N/R"
    Cells(1, "D").Value = "BB"
    Cells(1, "E").Value = "Contact"
    Cells(1, "F").Value = "BT"
    Cells(1, "G").Value = "TypeAAAUnit"
    Cells(1, "H").Value = "AAAJob1_Max"
    Cells(1, "I").Value = "AAAJob1_Min"
    Cells(1, "J").Value = "AAAJob1_BR50"
    'I omit some parts here.
    Cells(1, "V").Value = "Total P/per person"

For Each xFile In xFolder.Files
    Set New_WB = Workbooks.Open(xFile.Path)
        Main_WB.Sheets(1).Range("A" & X).Value = New_WB.Sheets(1).Range("C1").Value
        Main_WB.Sheets(1).Range("B" & X).Value = New_WB.Sheets(1).Range("C2").Value
        Main_WB.Sheets(1).Range("C" & X).Value = New_WB.Sheets(1).Range("C3").Value
        Main_WB.Sheets(1).Range("D" & X).Value = New_WB.Sheets(1).Range("C4").Value
        Main_WB.Sheets(1).Range("E" & X).Value = New_WB.Sheets(1).Range("C5").Value
        Main_WB.Sheets(1).Range("F" & X).Value = New_WB.Sheets(1).Range("C6").Value
        Main_WB.Sheets(1).Range("G" & X).Value = New_WB.Sheets(1).Range("B11").Value
        Main_WB.Sheets(1).Range("H" & X).Value = New_WB.Sheets(1).Range("D11").Value
        Main_WB.Sheets(1).Range("I" & X).Value = New_WB.Sheets(1).Range("E11").Value
        Main_WB.Sheets(1).Range("J" & X).Value = New_WB.Sheets(1).Range("F11").Value
        Main_WB.Sheets(1).Range("V" & X).Value = New_WB.Sheets(1).Range("O23").Value
        New_WB.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next xFile
End Sub
```

However, it doesn't work, so I modified some parts of my code. I deleted

`Main_WB.Sheets(1).Range("A" & X).Value = New_WB.Sheets(1).Range("C1").Value`

And changed it to:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(xRow, 0) = xFolder.Sheets(1).Range("C1").Value
ActiveCell.Offset(xRow, 1) = xFolder.Sheets(1).Range("C2").Value
ActiveCell.Offset(xRow, 2) = xFolder.Sheets(1).Range("C3").Value    
'repeat so omit...
xRow = xRow + 1
```

However, it still does not work. I want to directly fetch each cell because in these two Excel files, there are many cells and they are not in order. Any solutions?

Comment: When `X` is `0` (which it will be because you never set it to anything else) then `"A" & X` becomes `"A0"`.  Excel does not have a row 0, so `Range("A0")` will crash.

Comment: In your second bit of code, you are trying to use `xFolder.Sheets(1)` but `xFolder` isn't a `Workbook` object - I think you meant to use `New_WB.Sheets(1).Range("C1").Value`, etc, as you did in your first piece of code.

Comment: You never increment `X`. (e.g. `X = X + 1`)

Comment: @YowE3K yes, your right. I think the second modification is completely wrong. First one is correct. But in your comment, it seems I missed some part. `For X = 2 To 1000`....`Next X`

Comment: @ThomasInzina where do I need to add? In for-loop or outside?

Comment: Just like you are incrementing `xRow` in your second bit of code, you need to increment `X` in your first bit.  (But you also can't start `X` at `0` or it will fail - it looks like you want to initialise it to `2`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

X needs to be incremented.  I also refactored the code using a With Statement for better readability.

```
Sub Merge_Files()
    Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim xFolder As Folder
    Dim xFile As File
    Dim Main_WB As Workbook, New_WB As Workbook
    Dim X As Integer, Y As Integer
    Set Main_WB = ActiveWorkbook

    Set xFolder = FSO.GetFolder("C:\Desktop\MyFolder\")
    X = 1
    With Main_WB.Worksheets(1)
        .Range("A" & X).Value = "Company"
        .Range("B" & X).Value = "CB"
        .Range("C" & X).Value = "N/R"
        .Range("D" & X).Value = "BB"
        .Range("E" & X).Value = "Contact"
        .Range("F" & X).Value = "BT"
        .Range("G" & X).Value = "TypeAAAUnit"
        .Range("H" & X).Value = "AAAJob1_Max"
        .Range("I" & X).Value = "AAAJob1_Min"
        .Range("J" & X).Value = "AAAJob1_BR50"
        .Range("V" & X).Value = "Total P/per person"

        For Each xFile In xFolder.Files
            X = X + 1
            Set New_WB = Workbooks.Open(xFile.Path)
            .Range("A" & X).Value = New_WB.Sheets(1).Range("C1").Value
            .Range("B" & X).Value = New_WB.Sheets(1).Range("C2").Value
            .Range("C" & X).Value = New_WB.Sheets(1).Range("C3").Value
            .Range("D" & X).Value = New_WB.Sheets(1).Range("C4").Value
            .Range("E" & X).Value = New_WB.Sheets(1).Range("C5").Value
            .Range("F" & X).Value = New_WB.Sheets(1).Range("C6").Value
            .Range("G" & X).Value = New_WB.Sheets(1).Range("B11").Value
            .Range("H" & X).Value = New_WB.Sheets(1).Range("D11").Value
            .Range("I" & X).Value = New_WB.Sheets(1).Range("E11").Value
            .Range("J" & X).Value = New_WB.Sheets(1).Range("F11").Value
            .Range("V" & X).Value = New_WB.Sheets(1).Range("O23").Value
            New_WB.Close SaveChanges:=False
        Next xFile

    End With
End Sub
```